# why first print and second print got different result from function in python

Tags: python, printing, return, return-value

so i have func and i called it with lcg. the func have return value and i got the value i want.

> 6 7 2 11 14 15 10 3 6 7 2 11 14 15 10 3 # this is the result from func lcg

but after i called the func and print tes5, i just get result **3**

i don't know what wrong, so please help me to fix it

here's the code:

```
def lcg(n, m):
    a = 11
    c = 5
    dec = n
    m = m * 4
    for i in range(0,m):
        LCG = ((a*dec)+c) % m 
        print(LCG, end= ' ') # result = 6 7 2 11 14 15 10 3 6 7 2 11 14 15 10 3
        dec = LCG
        
    return LCG

tes5 = lcg(3, 4)
print(tes5)

print(tes5) # result = 3
```

Comment: In the end, you are returning only one value you should try returning a list instead

Comment: how to do it? @THUNDER07

Comment: li = [] at start , in each iteration li.append(LCG) return li at end

Comment: yeah it can, but can i remove the array? cause i don't need it @THUNDER07

Comment: if you remove the array don't expect tes5 to store all values

Comment: The main issue here is that you were using a print in the loop without \n to print all interim results; you never saved those. The function correctly returns only the last value actually calculated.

Comment: can i saved without using array? @Roland

Comment: The array, list to be precise, is the simplest way to do this in Python in a case like this, even if you only want to print the result. Create the empty list as suggested before your loop, use append during the loop, and return the list at the end, or use return(" ".join(li)) if you want a string as the result.